# Shimano Nexus 8 clicking noise

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub

The hub started making a clicking or crackling sound whenever the wheel turned (whether pedaling or not). After I let it sit for an hour then rode it again, the sound had become a grinding noise that repeated with every revolution of the wheel.

The wheel has under 200 miles but it is a very small 12.5 inch diameter wheel so I figured maybe it just needs grease. Local bike shop did an oil bath and the bike ran good, although a few of the gears felt like they occasionally slipped. Now after 5 miles riding the sound is back. There has been some oil seeped out and maybe this caused the problem to return?

I also noticed the sound is present when weight is on the hub, but not when the wheel is spinning free in the air.

Can anyone give me suggestions on what to do next? Thank you for reading. My bike is an attachable wheelchair handcycle, the wheel in question is the front wheel of the "trike" structure.

Comment: Recurring again after 5 miles, I'd probably be heading back to the local bike shop.  Would say even the 200mile mark there likely is something not right, assuming your the original owner, so is warranty an option?

Comment: Sounds like a manufacturing or assembly defect of the internal assembly (the thing that is taken out and dipped into oil), but hard to tell what is wrong, exactly.
In any case a bit of oil seeping out of a Nexus hub after oil bath routine is totally normal, those hubs are usually not sealed super well.

Comment: 200 miles? I’d do everything I could to get the seller to replace it. If it’s been built into a wheel you’re going to lose $ on labor unless you just really want to hold someone’s feet to the fire. Probably a tough spot because most wheelbuilders are pretty chill. But if you wait you’ll just fight this thing until it’s too late and no one will help.